# I have a YouTube video that when it finishes I would like to redirect to another page on my website

Tags: youtube-api

I have the video playing correctly, and there are several answers to my question on here but I can't for the life of me figure out where to append any of the solutions into my working code below

```
    <div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '700',
      width: '1600',
      videoId: 'MyVideo',
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0 }
    });
  }

</script>
```

Certainly would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the players `onStateChange` event to call a function of your own.

For Example

```
function VideoEnd(state){
if(state.data === 0){
 window.location="https://jsfiddle.net";
  }
}
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
   height: '300',
   width: '400',
   videoId: 'kvKLpJbIfn4',
   playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0,'modestbranding': 1, 'rel': 0 },
     events:{
       'onStateChange': VideoEnd
     }
 });
}
```

Here is a [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/68sj9mu0/)

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I well get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: OK I took the code as is from the JS Fiddle site and it ran fine with your targets. I subbed my targeted window.location and videoID and the video plays fine but just stays on my video thumbnail at the end instead of redirecting.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Did you add the `onStateChange` event property to the player? Please check your browser console for any errors.

Comment: I believe so since I copied the working code suggested and merely edited the video and redirect page targets.

Comment: Please check your browser console for errors . Also comment out the redriection and place a `console.log('video ended');` in there to test if the event,function is ever executed.